# Remove time from dynamically generated dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown that has times within a start and end time. I also have times displayed on my page that are "booked". I am trying to create a function that see if any "booked" values match the dropdown values, and if so, remove them from the array. I am having trouble figuring out how to design my JavaScript function to do so and would greatly appreciate any help in this.

remove.js

```
$(function () {
    var removeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('set');

    $('#time').find('option[value=="' + removeItem + '"]').remove();
});
```

time.js

```
var start = document.getElementById('start').innerHTML.split('.').join('').toLocaleLowerCase();
var end = document.getElementById('end').innerHTML.split('.').join('').toLocaleLowerCase();
var time = document.getElementById('time');

time.disabled = true;

var slotTimes = [];
document.getElementById("length").onchange = function (evt) {
    var timeDistance = evt.target.value;
    var startMoment = moment(start, "h:mm a");
    var endMoment = moment(end, "h:mm a");
    slotTimes = [];

    while (startMoment.isSameOrBefore(endMoment)) {
        slotTimes.push(startMoment.format("h:mm a"));
        startMoment = startMoment.add(timeDistance, 'minutes');
    }

    addDropdown();
    disabled();
};

function disabled(option) {
    if (option != "") {
        time.disabled = false;
    }
}

function addDropdown() {
    var doc = '',
        times = slotTimes,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        doc += "<option value='" + times[i] + "'>" + times[i] + "</option>";
    }

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = doc;
    disabled();
}
```

Comment: can you add a live example?

Answer (score 1):

First, you ought to be using jQuery!

`$('#foo')` is the same as `document.getElementById('foo')`

`$('.bar')` is the same as `document.getElementByClassName('bar')`

Now to address your question, you are trying to put an html element

ie `document.getElementByClassName('set')`

in place of a value.  Try running `console.log(removeItem)` and you will see what I mean.

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.set').each(function() { //loop over all elements with a class == 'set'

    const removeItem = $(this).val(); //get value of each element 

    $('#time').find('option=[value=="' + removeItem + '"]').remove();
  });

});
```

If you need any more help let me know.

Hope this helps!

### Update

You should put the `removeItem` loop at the end of the `addDropdown` function:

```
function addDropdown() {
    var doc = '',
        times = slotTimes,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
        doc += "<option value='" + times[i] + "'>" + times[i] + "</option>";
    }

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = doc;
    disabled();


  $('.set').each(function() { //loop over all elements with a class == 'set'

    const removeItem = $(this).val(); //get value of each element 

    $('#time').find('option=[value=="' + removeItem + '"]').remove();
  });
}
```

### Update 2

I would recommend rewriting your code to use the [selectpicker](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/) bootstrap package.  It looks like most of the "features" you are trying to make have simple keywords that [selectpicker](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/) uses.

For example, to disable an option from this dropdown:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="toppings">
  <option id="opt_1">Mustard</option>
  <option id="opt_2">Ketchup</option>
  <option id="opt_3">Relish</option>
</select>
```

You simply do:

```
$('#opt_2').prop('disabled', true);
```

If you need to reference specific specific options by their *parent* dropdown, you can use the [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
$('#toppings').children('.someClass').prop('disabled', true);
```

This will change all *options* of the `toppings` dropdown that have a `class="someClass"` to disabled.

I'm sure there are several features of the *selectpicker* package that you will find useful later on too!

I'm not sure what the problem is with your code specifically, but it is looking more and more like the *selectpicker* package, which you can use for free.

Comment: The function is not working as I believe it is running before the dynamic dropdown is created, since the dropdown only occurs when a "length" option is chosen, while the remove function starts from the beginning

Comment: When do you want to remove the dropdown option?

Comment: At the same time it is loaded, which I know is difficult and doesn't make much sense, but I can't have it before as the dropdown is not created until a user selects a "length", and I can't have it after as the dropdown will already be created

Comment: I added an update.  Let me know if you can't get it working.

Comment: The updated code doesn't make the "time" disabled, as it did before. Why is this issue occuring

Comment: Can you add the `disabled` function?  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: My mistake, I updated my code. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I fixed the disabled part, just a small typo; however, the value in the list is still not being removed